# Remove values from array on foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 68
            [type] => onetype
            [type_id] => 131
            [name] => name1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [type] => anothertype
            [type_id] => 101
            [name] => name2
        )
)
```

I need to remove some arrays from it if the users has permissions or not to see that kind of type. I am thinking on doing it with a for each, and do the needed ifs inside it to remove or let it as it.

My question is: What's the most efficent way to do this? The array will have no more than 100 records. But several users will request it and do the filtering over and over.

Comment: You want to remove one or a group of arrays  ???

Comment: Could you give us an example of the permissions boolean logic please?

Comment: What are the removal criteria? You can use a loop, or perhaps [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a custom callback function.

Comment: Use a temporary array to store the filtered results

Comment: It's also worth telling us where your array's coming from - if it's coming out of a database then that's the obvious place for optimisation, and if not, there may be other options depending on where exactly the data originates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this 1 simple and easy

```
foreach ($display_related_tags as $key => $tag_name) {
    if($tag_name == $found_tag['name']) {
       unset($display_related_tags[$key]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. This is the way I was thinking of using, and after some small research using the suggestions on the comments I choose this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function so that you could find the array that you would want to remove.

Then use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function to unset the array or variable that you would want to remove from your existing array.

On this way, you don't need to loop your array over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I think you understand the basics of PHP and stripping the array.

What you could do after stripping the array store it in a session for re-use after a page-refresh or loading of a different page. That way, you only have to do it once.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php